# How to force an HTML page load in mobile mode?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, webview

I tried to open a webview from a simple html page. Is it possible to add some javascript to the page to look like it loaded on an iPhone, or to make all elements react as if the resolution matches a mobile device?

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am loading a webview in react-native on an iPhone. And my problem is that the page is opened as if it's on desktop.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/UNu1w

Comment: Look into [viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) and [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution :

```
    <meta name="viewport" content='width=device-width, initialscale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0'>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yep, in chrome and firefox at least if you open developer tools, there is a window looking like icon in the top left of the dev tools panel, clicking on this will allow you mimic mobile views

Comment: I am loading a webview in react-native on an iPhone. And my problem is that the page is opened as if it's on desktop. 
imgur.com/a/UNu1w   I was curious if there is a way to fore it to load in mobile mode